# YoutubeThumbnailLoader taking too long to show a thumbnail?

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

Relevant code:

```
YouTubeThumbnailView first_video = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.main_video);

first_video.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
            final String video = getResources().getString(R.string.principal_funcoes);

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(video);
        }
```

The time it takes for the method 'youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(String s)" to work is absurd.
It takes 30+ seconds for a thumbnail to show up, with full cabled connection (100mbps).

It's definitely impossible for a user to wait more than 2 seconds for the thumbnail to show up, and have a completely blank screen while he waits for that to happen.

What can I do to load the video thumbnail any faster, or at least make YouTubeThumbnailView show a loading image while it fetches the thumbnail?

Comment: Have you tried choosing what [resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2108248/5995040) of the thumbnail you will use? And see if it loads the same as the other resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use direct youtube api urls for getting youtube thumbnails and they are way to faster too. here are urls you can try.

Start:-- It is only give you default size thumbnails.

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url similar to the HQ:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url similar to this:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

It helps me to develop youtube application, Hope it also help you.